# passing perl variables in perl file to php file

Tags: php, perl, include

I have a perl file and it has some useful variables.
 And I have to use those variables in a php file. I searched every where to find out how to include perl variables in to a php file.But every place is telling that "passing php vars to perl". But I want to do is vice versa of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possibilies depending on your workflow:

1) call script from command line - then you have to pass the variables as follow:

```
system('php /path/to/script.php arg1 arg2');
```

in script you receive arguments:

```
<?php
// $argv[0] is path to your script
$argument1 = $argv[1];
$argument2 = $argv[2];
?>
```

2) call script over url (an webserver):

```
use LWP::Simple;
get('http://localhost/path/to/your/script.php?firstvar=firstcontent&secondvar=secondcontent');
#OR on linux
system('wget http://localhost/path/to/your/script.php?firstvar=firstcontent&secondvar=secondcontent');
```

in script you receive arguments:

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You either pass them as command line arguments (e.g. via `system`) or you embed PHP in your Perl (e.g. with the [PHP module](https://metacpan.org/module/PHP)).

Comment: if your answer has more information,that's will help others too